# Relations between ideals and varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-writing

I am trying to collect all the relations between union and intersection
This far I have proved

1. $\cap I(W_i) = I(\cup W_i)$
2. $\cap V(I_i)=V(\cup I_i)=V(\sum I_i)$ where $<\cup I_i>=\sum I_i$
3. $\cup V(I_i)=V(\prod I_i)$ where $\prod I_i=\cap I_i$ if the ideals are comaximal (i think here $I$ has to be finite)
4. **What about $\cup I(W_i) = I(\cap W_i)$? It is clear that $\cup I(W_i) \subseteq I(\cap W_i)$ so, $\sum I(W_i) \subseteq I(\cap W_i)$. But can we say something more?**

Next, Let $X=V(a)\subseteq A^n$ be an algebraic set. TFAE:

- $X$ is an irreducible topological space;
- the ideal $\mathrm{rad}(a)$ is prime.

http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~bdrew/612/lec/612lec2.pdf

Comment: $I(\bigcup V_i)  = \bigcap I(V_i)$. For any ideal $J$ then $I(V(J)) = rad(J)$ and $V(J) = \bigcup V_i$ is union of irreducible algebraic sets (those whose ring of polynomials $k[X]/I(V_i)$ are integral domains, $I(V_i)$ are prime ideals) and $rad(J) = \bigcap I(V_i)$. If the $V_i$ are disjoint the $I(V_i)$ are comaximal and $\bigcap I(V_i) = \prod I(V_i)$

Comment: The union of two ideals need not be an ideal in general.